# Tratamento de Exceção Serviços REST Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, exceção, spring-boot

Em uma aplicação de serviços REST com Spring, onde deve ocorrer o tratamento/lançamento de exceções? No Controller ou Service?

Exemplo 1 - Tratar no Controller (No caso só estou retornando um badrequest como exemplo)

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Objeto> consultar(String foo) {
    Objeto objeto;
    try {
        objeto = objetoService.findByFoo(foo);
        if (objeto != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(objeto);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
}
```

Exemplo 2- Tratar no Service

```
public Objeto findByFoo(String foo) throws Exception {
    Objeto objeto = objetoRepository.findByFoo(foo);
    if(objeto != null){
        return objeto;
    } else {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Os dados são apenas ilustrativos.
No caso do service poderia estar tratando essa exception com um ControllerAdvice através de um ExceptionHandler de cada exceção.

Qual seria a forma mais correta de estar trabalhando com as exceções?

Comment: Na minha opnião isso deveria ser tratado no Controller. Vamos imaginar que em algum momento do projeto o metodo da service `findByfoo` precisa te retornar um objeto nulo e tomar outra logica, sem ser obrigatorio jogar esta excessao. Mas isso depende de caso a caso, vamos supor outro situação, para cadastrar uma determinada  entidade X voce precisa pesquisar uma entidade Y e so assim você pode cadastrar X, neste caso um tratamento/lançamento de exceção na service seria valido.

Comment: @ErickMaia, no caso o Controller não seria apenas uma porta de entrada dos meus dados via REST? E a questão de validação, até mesmo essa que deu exemplo, onde retorna um objeto nulo e precisa tomar outra lógica, não sei algo relacionado a regra de negócio que fica no service?

Answer (score 3):

O Controller só gerencia o fluxo das informações ela não deve conter regras de negocio e persistência em seu conteúdo.

Seria mais interessante você tratar as exceções na camada Service, assim você gerenciaria melhor as futuras alterações de regra caso você tivesse que recuperar informações de um DAO por exemplo.

Comment: Foi o que eu acabei fazendo, mas com um @ControllerAdvice. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Como o tratamento de erros bem como outros, como Logging, acesso a dados, etc... são chamados de [interesses transversais(cross cutting concerns)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern), o mais apropriado seria tratar as exceções disparadas por meio de um [Aspecto](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). O Spring permite você definir um [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice) que centralizaria o tratamento das exceções disparadas pelos `Controllers`.

Segue um exemplo de tratamento de erros para `ResourceNotFoundException`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {        

//....

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException rnfe,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

        ErrorDetail errorDetail = new ErrorDetail();
        errorDetail.setTimeStamp(new Date().getTime());
        errorDetail.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        errorDetail.setTitle("Recurso não encontrado.");
        errorDetail.setDetail(rnfe.getMessage());
        errorDetail.setDeveloperMessage(rnfe.getClass().getName());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetail, null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

//...

}
```

Essa classe `ErrorDetail` é uma classe que pode ser personalizada para os requisitos da sua aplicação:

```
public class ErrorDetail {

    private String title;
    private int status;
    private String detail;
    private long timeStamp;
    private String developerMessage;
    private Map<String, List<ValidationError>> errors = new HashMap<>();

//...
}
```

Comment: Foi o que fiz, coloquei todo o tratamento de exceções em um @ControllerAdvice. Obrigado.